# React fetch - Fetch fields based on user role

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, passport.js, auth0

more like a question on how to proceed.

I have a JSON which I fetch data from. Now say I want to have two user roles, one free and one premium. Is it possible to exclude premium data from fetching? (meaning that they will not show on Network tab too) An if yes, should I proceed with auth0.com or passport.js + MongoDB? Which is easier/friendlier for a newbie on react and why?

Comment: You need to do it on backend definitely. Add roles array to user model which represent acceptable user roles and then check on BE side if this user role includes needed auth role.

Comment: +1 to BE. All you can do on the front end is obscure views from users who aren't allowed access. But given they make it to the "premium page" you need to rely on the API returning a 401 or 403 to the client.

Comment: thank you everyone.. so as I understand, everything is done on the backend, and on the front (which just fetches the json). Right now I have the "client" side ready, and as I see I have two options, MERN stack and RBAC (based on the auth0.com). My BE (the API that is..) is built with Flask (python). Do I need to rewrite it for example to Express.js to implement a user model or can be done on Flask?